# Feature not implemented error message in appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

Getting error message "Feature not implemented" in Appium... Please help!

public class Login {

DesiredCapabilities caps;
    AndroidDriver driver;

```
@BeforeTest
public void test() throws MalformedURLException, WebDriverException, InterruptedException  {

    File appdir= new File("src");
    File app= new File(appdir, "ECare.apk");

    caps= new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,Platform.ANDROID);
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.4.16.1");
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
    //caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 300000);
    caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.HAS_TOUCHSCREEN, "True");
    driver=new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(9, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}


@Test
public void okOnAlert() throws InterruptedException
{
    WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert= driver.switchTo().alert();
    driver.findElementById("com.android.packageinstaller:id/dialog_container").getText();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    alert.accept();
}

@AfterTest
public void End()
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

}
[Trying to click on allow button but unable to click :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOvBr.png)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the entire error output and to have more information in which context the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switchTo().alert(); is not for mobile applications. You have to find Xpath of button which you want to click and perform click operation on that. For Example :

@findBy(id="android:/button1")
public WebElement ok;

// once you identified your element , click on the desired button.

ok.Click()
```

Comment: Please take a minute to format the code in your answer as code.

Comment: Thank you so much... I got to know where I was going wrong.. Thanks for the help! :)